# non-constant solution with inflection point for differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives, roots

If a nonconstant solution $y(t)$ to the autonomous DE $y' = f(y)$ has an inflection point at $t=a$, what must be true at $t=a$?

I am given three options: when $f(y) = 0$, when $f'(y) = 0$, and when $f''(y) = 0$.

Am I right in thinking that it must be $f'(y) = 0$ since to have an inflection point, we need $y'' = 0$ and $y'' = f'(y)$?

Comment: Yes, but be careful, as it is the point which curvature changes, the second derivative of $y(t)$ with **respect to time** must be equal to zero. Thus, the notation $f'(y)$ is a bit misleading, but still your thought process yields the correct answer.

Comment: okay, thank you!